# Subscribe and Publish in BASH like a receive Buffer

Tags: bash, mqtt, mosquitto

I want to buffer all messages of a subscription during processing publish messages.

The reason is a firmware update over MQTT. I want to send data with crc and the microcontroller have to verify the content and need to answer with new address pointer.
For now, i got it working without any interaction from the microcontroller. If size doesn't fit, or mc is not online, my bash script sends all the data of the binary file into the nirvana.

If I publish a message and subscribe directly after the publish, it is possible to lose an answer very easily.

But I'm not so experienced with bash and I need some suggestions how to do this...

This is what I have:

```
mosquitto_pub -h $MQTT_SERVER -t "spiffs/${client_name}/file_info" -m "$binary_file" -p 8883 -i "fw_server" --cafile server-cert.pem -d --insecure -u $MQTT_USER -P $MQTT_PW
mosquitto_sub -h $MQTT_SERVER -p 8883 -t "+/${client_name}/#" -i "fw_server" --cafile server-cert.pem -d --insecure -u $MQTT_USER -P $MQTT_PW | while read -r payload
do
    fp_jq_rspCode=".upload.fp"     # file pointer
    address=$(echo $payload | jq -r $fp_jq_rspCode)
    echo "${payload}" | jq -c  '.[]'
    echo "address pointer:$address"
    
    c=${address}

    addr=$(printf '%08x' "$c")
    content=$(xxd -p -c $payload_size -l $payload_size -seek $c $binary_file)
    length=`expr length "$content"`
    len=$(printf '%04x' "$length")
    crc32=$(echo -n "$content" | gzip -c | tail -c8 | hexdump -n4 -e '"%u"')
    crc32=$(printf '%08x' "$crc32")

    echo "$addr $len $content $crc32"
    message=$(printf '%08x%04x%s%s' "$c" "$length" "$content" "$crc32")
    mosq=$(mosquitto_pub -h $MQTT_SERVER -t "spiffs/${client_name}/upload" -m "$message" -p 8883 -i "fw_server" --cafile server-cert.pem -d --insecure -u $MQTT_USER -P $MQTT_PW)
done
```

Comment: I would suggest NOT doing this in bash, there is a timing window between the first 2 commands that can not be overcome. You need to subscribe before sending the first mesage.

Comment: Yes I know. Maybe with coproc?
Otherwise I could use Phython or Perl?

Comment: You can use pretty much any language with a proper MQTT client library, without knowing what languages you are familiar with it's hard to say, but I'd pick Python over Perl (on principal) as it has a Paho library

Comment: I use fhem for home automation for about 3 years, and its Perl. I did a lot with Perl there, but i dont like Perl very much. I dont like Bash too, because of it's "unconvenient" syntax. I'm familiar with Visual Basic and C++, but I think its necessary to learn new things, wich have a big community. I did some little things in Python before, and now, I will start to write my firmware uploader with Python. Thanks!

Comment: I did with Python. Much easier!